# Listview in nested linear layout not showing in runtime

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

My "graphical design" has four rows of textviews and a listview below the textview, everything is nested in linear layouts.

My xml code behind the design is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="left" android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvs_pname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Project Name:" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_pname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large Text" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvs_pamount" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Budgeted Amout:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_pamount" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvs_pstartdate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Start Date:" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_pstartdate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large Text" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvs_penddate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="End Date:" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_penddate" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView android:id="@+id/lst_projlist"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

the problem is that when I run my app on emulator the textviews appear just like the design but the listview does not appear below it. Why is this happening.

Experimentally I deleted the listview from my code and out a button there instead. when I ran my app both the textview and button appeared in the emulator just like the design.

So what is the problem with my code?? Am I missing some property in the listview??
I'm a total newbie so I know I could be making a very basic mistake

Comment: Do you have any items in the ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added an element in your listview?
Dont know if this is the solution - working not so often with emulator, but try it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you populating the `ListView` with data via some kind of `Adapter` in your code? If the list has no items in it, it will be "invisible" because it has nothing to display.

If you are, you can use the [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html) tool with the emulator to analyze how your layout is being rendered, and see where the ListView might be.

You might also experiment with [layoutopt](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/layoutopt.html) to ensure that you're using the most optimal layout for your whole screen. I see a lot of nested `LinearLayouts` that could probably be eliminated in favor of, say, `TableLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right. Probably you haven't filled the list in your code.
Try, for example to add this line to your onCreate() method:

> ListView lst_projlist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lst_projlist);

```
    for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
        elements.add("element "+i);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, elements);
    lst_projlist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thnks to all the repliers! ur all correct! I hadn't bothered to setting up the data for the list. thought I could test the layout first..now that I'v done that.. its working perfectly:D